# Where store fetch array data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I try [eventArray value]    but nothing - i get like that 
78999
3451237
3451237

But must be 
90

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];   
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
[request setEntity:entity];   
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"values" ascending:NO];  
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];  
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  
[sortDescriptor release];   
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];   
if (!mutableFetchResults) { }    
[self setEventArray: mutableFetchResults];  
event = [eventArray objectAtIndex:3];
NSNumber * info = [event values];
printf("\n%d", [event values]);
[mutableFetchResults release];  
[request release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the `event` variable here:

```
event = [eventArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

is an NSManagedObject whose entity has a numerical attribute named `values`. If so, then `[event values]` will return an NSNumber instance and not an int or double. Therefore, this line:

```
printf("\n%d", [event values]);
```

... will not print out the double value of the returned NSNumber instance but instead a decimal representation of the instances address in memory. To log the actual value you need to use:

```
printf("\n%d", [[event values] intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!mutableFetchResults) { }
```

any explanation for that ?

Comment: if (!mutableFetchResults) {
  // Handle the error.
  // This is a serious error and should advise the user to restart the application
 }

Comment: Right, but right here you do not check if there is an error... your false result may come from that ? try a NSLog to check it out